# Add ReCaptcha to SmartCapture Form in Cloud Pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, cloudpage, smart-capture

We are trying to implement Google Recaptcha v2 into our Smart Capture form within a Cloud Page.   Here's what we've done so far:

1. Created a Data Extension
2. Created Cloud Pages Collection
3. Added Cloud Pages Landing Page to the Collection
4. Included a Smart Capture form associated with Data Extension within Landing Page
5. Included Form Page snippets per AmpScript XYZ: https://ampscript.xyz/how-tos/how-to-implement-google-recaptcha-on-marketing-cloud-forms/

The front end seems to be working correctly.  However, it's not clear where/how we can enter the AmpScript or ss js into the form handler.  Is there any way to edit the form handler per the Form Handler Page instructions on AmpScript XYZ?

Comment: You could potentially hack a SmartCapture, but why? Follow Adam's tutorial using CloudPages and normal HTML forms, rather than SmartCaptures. The form handler page could be the same CloudPage with some logic around whether it's being GETed from or POSTed to. It could be a separate page that returns a JSON/XML response to an AJAX request from your form page or it could be a separate page where form data's posted to that says, "thanks" or "oops". The basics are in Adam's tutorial and all the rest is fairly standard non-SFMC specific web developement stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My tutorial is not meant to be used with SmartCapture ;)

SmartCapture is inferior to custom built web forms in every possible way, I don’t recommend using it.